# How to confine flex-grow div within position: relative divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to create a basic slider with `div`, I got the structure.

I have parent `div` with class `slider` three children `div` called button1 buttpn2 and range, and I want buttons to `display: relative` so that when I use `left` or `right` property on the button it should move.

I realised that it is `position: relative`, but how to make desired slider effect?

code: https://jsfiddle.net/L0bjqdee/

```css
.slider {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.button {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#button1 {
  left: 25px;
}

#button2 {
  right: 50px;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="button" id="button1"></div>
  <div class="range"></div>
  <div class="button" id="button2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set position: relative on the containing div, not the buttons.  Set the buttons to position: absolute;

```css
.slider{
  width:300px;
  height:5px;
  background-color:#a0a0a0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  position: relative;
}
.slider div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.button{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
}
#button1{
  left:25px;
}
#button2{
  right:50px;
}
.button:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.range{
  flex-grow:2;
  height:5px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="button" id="button1"></div>
    <div class="range"></div>
    <div class="button" id="button2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the blue part should be in between red button!

Comment: I'm just trying to help with what you've asked, not do all your work for you!